# Teamcity. How to force the browser to view an artifact, instead of download it?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I want to be able to click on the link in a TeamCity build log which opens an artifact's log, but I can only get one of them to open in browser window. The other one downloads the log. Can anyone tell me why a browser will view onscreen a teamcity log from this link...

`http://teamcity.internal:8111/repository/download/Test_Gcc/7537:id/Libtest.Makefile.bld_log.txt`

.. but will only download that log from this link ...

`http://teamcity.internal:8111/app/rest/builds/buildType:Test_Gcc,number:35/artifacts/content//Libtest.Makefile.bld_log.txt`

- Artifact `Libtest.Makefile.bld_log.txt` is a text log.
- `Test_Gcc` is the `teamcity.buildType.id`
- `35` is the `build.number` which i want to use.
- `7537` is the rather useless `teamcity.build.id` as far as the user is concerned.

Both links hit the same log, just 2 different methods. I want the log from the `build.number` because that is what the user sees as the number of the current build, but that endpoint can only download the log rather than viewing it.  Any ideas to try ?

One extra fact is in the url that does not work has header.

`Content-Disposition: Libtest.Makefile.bld_log.txt`

whereas the one that works had this.

`Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Libtest.Makefile.bld_log.txt";`

Anyone know how to make TC add the latter ?